# GET from API in Azure Data Factory without duplicating URLs

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am quite new to Azure and I am struggling with the following workflow:

- Do a GET request to `/some/base/url/endpoint_credentials` obtaining ephemeral credentials in JSON format. `{ID: PASS}`
- Do a GET request to `/some/base/url/endpoint_data` (there are many data endpoints actually) using the previous credential as part of the header and get some JSON data `{filed1: value1, field2: value2, etc..}`
- Write te data in the file system.

My approach is

- create a `HTTP` linked service pointing to `/some/base/url`.
- create two DataSets pointing to each endpoint.
- use the two `web` activities to retrive the desired data (one for credentials, one for data)
- write it in the filesystem.

The problem I've got is that `Web` activity force you to write the URL instead of using those provided by the linked service + dataset, which seems to be not optimal since you are force to write the whole URL in each pipeline instead of make use of a reusable components as linked services or datasets.

I've worked with `SSIS` in the past and this kind of operations were pretty easy to develop. I guess my approach is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct. 
Make use of [Set Variable Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity). Retrieve the credentials from the first web activity and store the credentials using the set variable activity. Make use of those variables in setting up the URL as [dynamic content](https://www.blue-granite.com/blog/using-azure-data-factory-v2-activities-dynamic-content-to-direct-your-files) of web activity.

Below is the way to set up the URL in web activity with dynamic content. Make sure you are setting up those variable in the first web activity. In case, you need to make use of multiple pipelines, pass those variables to the calling pipeline parameters and make use of those parameters in the URL.

[image: Setting Up URL at run time using variables set in other activity]

Basically dynamic content let's you decide the values at runtime.